# how to hide "Edit" option which comes from table plugin of wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Through shortcode of table plugin (tablepress) i have displayed the table on normal php page. But along with table it also shows "edit" in the last row of table. When i inspect it it is cwrapped  in caption and anchor tag. On display: none it goes but comes gain after updating table. how to permanently hide that "edit" word from not coming?

---

### HTML

```
<table id="tablepress-1" class="tablepress tablepress-id-1 stylingtable footable"> 

<caption style="caption-side:bottom;text-align:left;border:none;background:none;margin:0;padding:0;">
 <a href="http://jugalmathuria.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=tablepress&action=edit&table_id=1">Edit</a> 
</caption>....</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Can provide a Jquery Solution for this.

May be this help

```
var removeEdit = $.trim($('#tablepress-1 a').text().toUpperCase());
if(removeEdit =='EDIT'){$('#tablepress-1 a').text('')}
```